# Build features are included in TFS 2013 or require additional TFS Build product?

Tags: tfsbuild

I used TFS in the past, but if I recall we had a separate product referred to as "TFS Build".  Is that included with the 2013 version, or is there still a separate product that will let me schedule builds for example to be deployed to a test server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS Build was never a separate *product*, but you have to configure it separately from the Application Tier. This is by-design as many prefers to run builds on a separate server, a good practice for any sizable team; for example, in my organization I have about 20 build servers, with different software installed. A small team, less than 10 people, can keep everything on a single machine.

For details on configuring the Build feature [see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252495.aspx).

Comment: Ahh, now I remember, its a build service, not a separate product.